# Import contacts from outlook to iphone

Tags: iphone

How can I import my contact from outlook 2010 to IPhone ?

I have windows 7 x64 bits

Comment: and how in your wildest dreams is that programming related?

Comment: @Reza dude .. get itunes and fiddle with it a bit ...

Comment: @Mitch , you are right , it has nothing to do with programming

Comment: @scartag I installed itunes on windows but it doesnt have contacts :(

Comment: @Reza Connect your iphone to your computer via its usb cable. it should show up in itunes .. look under devices .. select your device... the screen that shows up has tabs .. select the "info" tab. options to sync outlook contacts are there ... Hope this helps ...

Comment: thanks scartage , it works please write it as answer that I can mark it as answer

Comment: @Reza ... glad it helped ... i've added it as an answer ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Connect your iphone to your computer via its usb cable. it should show up in itunes .. look under devices .. select your device... the screen that shows up has tabs .. select the "info" tab. options to sync outlook contacts are there ...

Hope this helps ...

Answer (score 0):

You can export contacts from outlook as CSV files and import in iOS

Comment: I need to import to Iphone not android